# How do I capture a smart pointer in a lambda?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, lambda

What is best way to capture a smart pointer in a lambda? One attempt of mine lead to a use-after-free bug.

Example code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::function<const char *(const char *)> test(const char *input);

int main()
{
  std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::function<const char *(const char *)> a = test("I love you");
  const char *c;
  while ((c = a(" "))){
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
std::function<const char *(const char *)> test(const char *input)
{
  char* stored = strdup(input);
  char *tmpstorage = nullptr;
  std::shared_ptr<char> pointer = std::shared_ptr<char>(stored, free);
  return [=](const char * delim) mutable -> const char *
  {
    const char *b = strtok_r(stored, delim, &tmpstorage);
    stored = nullptr;
    return b;
  };
}
```

fails, as shown by AddressSanitizer.

Comment: Well, there's currently no way to capture a `std::unique_ptr` other than by reference, as you cannot move it in until C++14.

Comment: @chris You could, however, capture the pointer handled by `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, Fair point.

Comment: @MarkGarcia presumably that kind of thing is what leads to the "use after free bug".

Comment: @juanchopanza If I'll have a bug like that then I'll consider my use of lambdas in the first place. As you see, lambdas generally should have as small scope as possible, preferably not change state. So if I'll capture that pointer in a lambda used in `std::find` or some other algorithm, I'll generally not worry about ownership problems.

Comment: @MarkGarcia but for that he will have to use `release()` right?

Comment: @Koushik There's [`std::unique_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get).

Comment: @MarkGarcia, As long as you can be sure it's valid for the entire time the lambda uses it ;)

Comment: @MarkGarcia but get() will not release the ownership is'nt it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lambda (even one with a universal capture like `[=]`) only actually captures variables used within its definition. Since in your example, `pointer` is never used inside the lambda, it's not captured and thus when it goes out of scope, it's the last shared pointer referring to `stored` and `free()` is called.

If you want to capture `pointer`, you could force its use:

```
return [=](const char * delim) mutable -> const char *
{
  pointer;
  const char *b = strtok_r(stored, delim, &tmpstorage);
  stored = nullptr;
  return b;
};
```

However, this is rather hackish. You want your functor stateful and with nontrivial state management. To me, this is a strong indicator an actual named class (instead of a lambda) would be in order. So I would change it like this:

```
std::function<const char *(const char *)> test(const char *input)
{
  struct Tokenizer
  {
    std::shared_ptr<char> pointer;
    char* stored;
    char* tmpstorage;
    explicit Tokenizer(char* stored) : pointer(stored, free), stored(stored), tmpstorage(nullptr) {}
    const char* operator() (const char * delim)
    {
      const char *b = strtok_r(stored, delim, &tmpstorage);
      stored = nullptr;
      return b;
    }
  };
  return Tokenizer(strdup(input));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just capture the variable by value and let the copy constructor and destructor worry about ownership semantics- that's what smart pointers are for.

Comment: I tried that - the destructor fired too soon, and the memory was prematurely freed.

Comment: @Demetri it sounds like your smart pointer isn't that smart. What type is it?

Comment: @Demetri, Could you elaborate on what exactly you did, as in show minimal code in the question?